# Auto populate django models and views while creating an app

Tags: django

I am pretty new to Django and still learning. The question is that i know that an empty app can be created in django and then i can add models and views. But throughout a long time of making websites, I noticed that most of the time i am doing operating on dbs like update,del or insert. Now my question is that is there anyway that i can add the model parameters while creating the app itself in django and it automatically populated models,forms and views for me for the basic operations that i mentioned above.
That way i can create DBS architecture while i am creating the app and the only way that i am left with is to review and make changes in models if any.

Just to make sure that i am understood, i am attaching a snippet of what i am trying to say which is wrong but i hope that it gives a better idea

`//Not real code Purpose only to give a better understanding to question
python manage.py startapp test --fields id=int verified=bool`

Or if there is not is there any zsh plugin / 3rd party plugin that might be helpfull

Also i should mention that the need originated from a current project which is a one page application and has lots of tables but no operations on it. So the task to write models everytime would be tedious and not the correct way. So any other suggestions are also greatly appreciated

Comment: How is this different from creating a `models.py` file and defining the fields there? A field is not as simple as its data type, you have to specify indexing, uniqueness, nullability etc. too.

Comment: @Selcuk i know what i mean to say is that it just generated a sample model. Refinements can be made manually. Basically the issue is for every app i need to edit 4 files models,views,forms and urls. I needed to know if there was something that could automatically atleast build a basic structure for all of them and then if i needed refinements i could do them manually. Would save a lot of tedious work :)

Comment: You don't have to edit views, forms, and urls as Django admin will auto generate them for you. You just have to create the models.py, which imho is not much harder than passing those arguments.

Comment: @Selcuk not sure what you mean by django admin will generate them. I am relatively new to django, so from what i know that when i startapp, the files are generated but they are empty. What i mean is rather that that based on model preferences as passed, it automatically creates urls and forms to update,create ... I am not saying that i can't do that. But for the current app that i am working on, it is just adding data,fetching etc no operations whatsoever. so from my side a smarter way would be that i only write models and django/some plugin writes other stuff

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that, if you simply want to create a CRUD (Create/Read/Update/Delete) application, Django admin will be sufficient: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: I will need to have a look at that one and maybe change something over there because not everyone who is accessing is super user. But anyway i think that it is a possibility that i can work around. Thanks :)

Comment: You can create other staff users who are _not_ superusers. Django admin is fairly powerful, you should read more about it.

Comment: Django Admin is introduced very early in [Django first steps tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/). You should really consider reading through this whole tutorial.

Comment: You have also standard create update and delete model forms that can be setup with a couple of lines of code ;-)